# Ajax.BeginForm results in redirect to partial view instead of in-place

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

My Search.cshtml has a div named "search-results" that is to be updated. SearchResults is the action name. I have done this many times on MVC2/VS2008 projects, but this is my first using MVC3 and VS2010.

The problem is, instead of my search result being rendered in my div, it clicking submit is redirecting me displaying my partial as a standalone page.

I have read that this may be because Ajax is not enabled.  My _Layout.cshtml looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/2011.2.712/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/2011.2.712/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.css").Add("telerik.transparent.css").Combined(true).Compress(true))) 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>

            @(Html.Telerik().Menu()
                    .Name("menu")
                    .Items(menu => {
                        menu.Add().Text("Home").Action("Index", "Home");
                        menu.Add().Text("About").Action("About", "Home");
                        menu.Add().Text("Employees").Action("List", "Employee");
                    }))
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            @RenderBody()
            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)))</body>
</html>
```

Do I need to add MicrosoftMvcAjax.js or jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in? My web.config (root) contians the following:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" /> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" /> 
  </appSettings>
```

If I add MicrosoftMvcAjax.js in at the end of the  element, I get an error sayning namespace 'Type' is undefined error from the first line of MicrosoftMvcAjax.js:

```
    Type.registerNamespace('Sys.Mvc');Sys.Mvc.$create_AjaxOptions=function(){return {};}
```

What am I missing here.  I am sure my code is fine, as it copied alsmost verbatim from my MVC2 projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page (adjust the path as necessary):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As far as `Microsoft*.js` scripts are concerned, they are obsolete in ASP.NET MVC 3 and should no longer be used unless you are porting some legacy application. They have been replaced by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out my problem.

I was calling Ajax.BeginForm with the AjaxOption OnSuccess pointint to a js function that updated my place holder.  But this is not needed, with unobtrusive. Once I removed the OnSucces from the Ajax options everything started working.

~S