# Ajax.BeginForm redirect instead of replacing div container

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ajax.BeginForm results in redirect to partial view instead of in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651591/ajax-beginform-results-in-redirect-to-partial-view-instead-of-in-place)

How can i fix ajax redirecting in mvc 4 razor?

```
 <div id="ajax-container">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditPlace", "Index", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "ajax-container" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Site)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.WorkTime)
    <input type="submit" value="ОК" />
}
```

Server side:

```
public void EditPlace(int id, string name, string address, string phone, string site, string worktime)
    {
        var company = _entity.Companies.FirstOrDefault(linqCompany => linqCompany.Id == id);
        if (company == null)
            return;
        company.Name = name;
        company.Address = address;
        company.Phone = phone;
        company.Site = site;
        company.WorkTime = worktime;
        _entity.SaveChanges();
    }
```

After button click I was redirected on Index/EditPlace.

Comment: Have you referenced the `"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"` in your layout/view? It is required for the `Ajax.BeginForm` and `Ajax.ActionLink` to make them work.

Comment: It's help me, thank you! I just create new project without scripts and it was my fail.